# Letter combinations of a phone number too many combinations in output?

Tags: python, backtracking

I'm working on [Leetcode 17: Letter combinations of a phone number](https://leetcode.com/problems/letter-combinations-of-a-phone-number/) but my first attempt results in too many combinations in the output.

> Given a string containing digits from 2-9 inclusive, return all possible letter combinations that the number could represent. Return the answer in **any order**. A mapping of digits to letters (just like on the telephone buttons) is given below. Note that 1 does not map to any letters.

```py
def letterCombinations(self, digits: str) -> List[str]:
        if not digits:
            return []
        digit_map = {
            '2': 'abc',
            '3': 'def',
            '4': 'ghi',
            '5': 'jkl',
            '6': 'mno',
            '7': 'pqrs',
            '8': 'tuv',
            '9': 'wxyz'
        }
        combinations = []
        def generate_combinations(combination, digits):
            if not digits:
                combinations.append(combination)
                return
            for digit in digits:
                for ch in digit_map[digit]:
                    generate_combinations(combination+ch, digits[1:])
            
        generate_combinations('', digits)
        return combinations
```

The input "234" results in the output `["ad","ae","af","bd","be","bf","cd","ce","cf","dd","de","df","ed","ee","ef","fd","fe","ff"]`. I tried drawing out the recursive tree for my solution above.
[image: wrong_solution_tree]. I modified my code to just take into account the first digit in digits for the code below.

```
def letterCombinations(self, digits: str) -> List[str]:
        if not digits:
            return []
        digit_map = {
            '2': 'abc',
            '3': 'def',
            '4': 'ghi',
            '5': 'jkl',
            '6': 'mno',
            '7': 'pqrs',
            '8': 'tuv',
            '9': 'wxyz'
        }
        combinations = []
        def generate_combinations(combination, digits):
            if not digits:
                combinations.append(combination)
                return
            digit = digits[0]
            for ch in digit_map[digit]:
                generate_combinations(combination+ch, digits[1:])
            
        generate_combinations('', digits)
        return combinations
```

which gives the correct solution. Again, I tried drawing out the recursive tree.
[image: right_solution_tree]. Is the first solution wrong because once a digit from the input is used, it should *not* ever be used again? Also, I'm trying to analyze the time and space complexity for the correct solution. Let `N` = len(digits).

- Time complexity: `O(N*4^N)`. The branching factor of the tree is `4` b/c some digits like `7` and `9` are mapped to four different letters (`7->pqrs`) and (`9->wxyz`). Then because strings are immutable in python, it's an `O(N)` operation to make a copy of `combination` and pass it to each recursive call. The tree has a height of `N`.
- Space complexity: `O(N)`

Can someone let me know if my complexity analysis is right?

Answer (score 0):

The first solution is trivially wrong because it only generates 2-character strings for a 3-character input, while the problem defines that the correct correct output for a n-character input is a list of n-character strings. This is due to your choice to iterate over the full remaining input string in each recursive call, which is implemented in a fashion which causes truncation of the last digit:

```
    for digit in digits:
        for ch in digit_map[digit]:
```

This is unnecessary since in each recursive operation you only need to handle one character - the next character in the input string, not all of them.

Regarding your complexity analysis, the best possible runtime complexity for a solution to this problem is O(4^N) since you are generating O(4^N) items, which inherently requires O(4^N) operations at minimum. Your analysis for your solution seems correct. It might be an interesting challenge to consider how to reduce your runtime complexity further, however solving additional problems is likely a better use of your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

given example of "23", this is what we want to achieve:

[image]

- 2 is mapped to "abc"
- 3 is mapped to "def"
- we need to do mapping from each letter in "abc" to each letter in "def".

  ad ae af

  bd be bf

  cd ce cf

for each letter in "abc", we have to write a for-loop

```
def letterCombinations(self, digits: str) -> List[str]:
    if not digits:
        return []
    digit_map = {
        '2': 'abc',
        '3': 'def',
        '4': 'ghi',
        '5': 'jkl',
        '6': 'mno',
        '7': 'pqrs',
        '8': 'tuv',
        '9': 'wxyz'
    }
    combinations = []
    def generate_combinations(combination,position):
        if position==len(digits):
            combinations.append(combination)
            return
        
        for ch in digit_map[digits[position]]:
            generate_combinations(combination+ch, position+1)
        
    generate_combinations('', 0)
    return combinations
```

you will be pushing `backtrack("",0)` to the call stack. In the first for-loop it will add "a" and then call `backtrack("a",1)`. Now in `backtrack("a",1)` function it will run for-loop for "def" and each letter in "def" to the "a" so you will be creating "ad ae af". After this for loop is done it will do same for "b" and "c"